# Turn information in a single column into multiple columns

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a dataframe in R where one column has a subset of codes in it. For example,

```
 df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:3,
  y = c("a", "d,e,f", "g,h"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

I would like to end up with a dataframe where the first column is the key ("x") and then a column for "a", "b", "c", ... where each row has a 1 or 0 for if that value is present for the given key value. I don't know how many of these variables I have before hand. 
I have tried

```
n_vars <- df$y %>% str_split(",") %>% lappy(function(z) length(z)) %>% unlist() %>% max()
df <- separate(df, y, sep = ",", into = as.character(1:n_vars))
```

I'm unsure of what the next steps would be. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a perfect case for `cSplit_e` from `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit_e(df, "y", type = "character", fill = 0, drop = TRUE)

#  x y_a y_d y_e y_f y_g y_h
#1 1   1   0   0   0   0   0
#2 2   0   1   1   1   0   0
#3 3   0   0   0   0   1   1
```

---

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, we can use `separate_rows` and `spread`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate_rows(y) %>%
  mutate(n = 1) %>%
  spread(y, n, fill = 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's perfect!